# Fedora Host, Kali VM, KVM/QEMU mouse not working

Tags: fedora, kali-linux, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I have a Fedora 23 host, and I tried to install Kali Linux using Virtual Machine Manager, and every time I did it -- no matter how I configured it -- the mouse would not work. It would only go down and to the right, never up and left.